# How do I make my media keys work again?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, multimedia

I am using a ThinkPad Edge 11. After the installation I replaced Banshee with Rhythmbox. Everything worked fine for 4 weeks but all of a sudden the media keys stopped working.

I need to press and hold the Fn button to use the media keys. I ran

```
$ sudo showkey
```

and it shows that I press the Fn button (Code 143) but nothing when i then press one of the media keys (F1 to F9 to be precise). The media keys from F11 to F12 work (play/pause and next track).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved itself after the last kernel update.

```
$ sudo showkey
```

also shows each key again. Case closed.

Comment: accept your own answer, when you can. :) (you need to wait 2 days I think..)